# Visual Studio Code change font size for file explorer tray?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the font size for the file explorer in Visual Studio Code?  There is not an option in the settings.json file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774918/vs-code-customize-sidebar

Comment: You can track progress of this feature at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519

Comment: @DanielImms The explorer tray is the one with the icons, it's not the same as the sidebar. Explorer icons change what is shown in the sidebar.

Comment: @AdvaitJunnarkar technically "explorer tray" is not a thing in VS Code, what you're referring to is called the "activity bar". Pretty sure the OP is talking about the sidebar aka the viewlet.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this isn't a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51456526/11107541

Answer (score 277):

I've found that setting the zoom level in settings.json works well for this:

```
"window.zoomLevel": 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that zooms all the windows/panes, so I would have to make the font size in the editor windows smaller to compensate.

Comment: It also makes the fonts blurry, since everything is just zoomed. An actual setting for this would be far preferable. There also seems to be quite a jump from zero to one, and something like .5 is not allowed.

Comment: one issue i found with this is default font on linux does not look good when zoomed out.. even -0.5

Comment: if suffering from editor font size you can turn on zooming by mouse wheel + CTRL, just search for zoom in settings ...

Comment: in the most recent version, I had to type this in the search field in the `preferences` and it automatically showed me a number I can increment and decrement.

Comment: @Kallaste - `zoomLevel` allows fractional numbers now, but as you say, an actual setting for this would be better. (Also, the `zoomLevel` units are...odd. Each whole number is 20%. So 1 = 120%, 2 = 140%, ... o_O)

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the OP asked. How is this the highest rated answer?

Answer (score 99):

I have set

`"window.zoomLevel": -1` and 
`"editor.fontSize": 16.5`

it works great here's a preview,

[image: here's a preview]

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: in the most recent version, I had to type this in the search field in the `preferences` and it automatically showed me a number I can increment and decrement.  `window.zoomLevel`

Comment: I like this hack but I wish explorer had it's own font size setting

Comment: works really nicely

Answer (score 58):

[image]

Sample value : `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`, ...

I have mine set to `0`, like this `"window.zoomLevel": 0,`

Save the file, you will see the effect right the way.

[image]

Comment: in the most recent version, I had to type this in the search field in the `preferences` and it automatically showed me a number I can increment and decrement.

Answer (score 36):

I'm visually impaired and I had the same problem, my solution was

1. "Zoom Out" until I achieved my desired Explorer size (CTRL-), everything will be zoomed out.
2. Edit the settings.json and change the "fontSize"  to 20 as reflected in my settings.json.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/apps/php 7.0.14/php.exe"
}
```

Comment: For those that want the file explorer a smaller font size (for navigability and because you don't stare at it all the time) and the editor size the size you want, this is the solution for you.

Answer (score 22):

Type CTRL+SHIFT+P inside your VSCODE window and type/select "Open Settings (JSON)"

If you find the default font settings tiny (very much like I do), inside the curly brackets type:

```
"editor.fontSize": 16,
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
"window.zoomLevel": 1.4,
```

Try changing the sizes until it works for you

Comment: none of these actual change the size of the explorer, and you can check the docs to confirm none of them are related.

Comment: @user4893106 I can confirm is window.zoomLevel.  You need to save the file.

Answer (score 17):

You can try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for zoom in

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for zoom out

Answer (score 10):

I found what worked for me was `"window.zoomLevel": 0.25, "editor.fontSize": 12`

Answer (score 6):

Here another solution but it needs done at every update.
Open (windows)

```
 C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.css
```

Then look for the **first**

```
  .part>.content
```

And replace the size.

```
  .part>.content{font-size:13px}
```

Answer (score 4):

The decent way to do is to edit the `"window.zoomLevel": 0`, It changes everything on the screen from Project Explorer to your Font.

Also, You can customize only the font by `"editor.fontSize": 15`

P.S 15px is my personal choice.

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is, you can make your window zoom level small and increase the font size, It will decrease the size of the window and font size you can select of your own size.

My MacBook Pro 16 settings.json is :

{

```
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"editor.fontSize": 14,
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Shortcut for increasing font size of just the file explorer in VSCode ->

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Shortcut for decreasing font size of just the file explorer in VSCode ->

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. This worked for terminal as well.
On Mac, it is "cmd + shift + ="

Comment: These shortcuts are not resolving the issue , it is increasing font size all over the editor not specifically the file explorer section .

Answer (score 1):

Been looking for this answer for a while now. Finally found it on a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783324.

Essentially you override the keyboard shortcuts for View:ZoomIn and View:ZoomOut with the ones for "Editor Font Zoom In" and "Editor Font Zoom Out". Note that you don't need remove the View-based shortcuts, just enter the Editor ones and they'll move to the top and override.

Works perfect.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_font-zoom-commands

Kudos to [czen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9905322/cezn)

Answer (score 1):

Version: 1.43.1 (user setup)
Date: 2020-03-18T07:01:20.184Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64

Its under 'window zoom' in 'settings'

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.json` increment zoomLevel

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fernando Rodrigues for introducing

> APC Customization UI++

vscode extension
The solution works perfectly, but it disturbs the layout of the terminal window pane as well. Upon digging into settings, I found the following solution which only targets the VSCode File Explorer view pane:

```
"apc.stylesheet": {
  ".explorer-folders-view": "zoom: 1.17; transform-origin: 0 0;"}
```

Furthermore, the following settings can also be used to adjust font size and line spacing of the folder tree view:

```
"apc.font.family": "Sintony",  // changes font of Explorer tree, Menu, context menu etc in VsCode

"apc.listRow": {
  "lists": ["explorer-folders-view"],
  "fontSize": 13,
  "height": 21  // line spacing between folder tree
```

},

Adjusting the zoom level also makes the file icon clearer on a big screen. Thanks to Fernando Rodrigues for finding out those settings.
Adjusting font size and spacing makes the explorer tree view very comfortable.

This revised solution Works PixelPerfect.

[Screenshot of VSCode setting and File explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giDts.png)

Answer (score 0):

My settings with colours as IntelliJ

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Darkula",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "java.import.gradle.java.home": "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home",
    "window.zoomLevel": -0.3,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 12,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
    "chat.editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.fontLigatures": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution if you don't want your whole screen to be zoomed in (just like I did).

You can change the **CSS inside the code** using an experimental extension called `APC`.

[image: APC Customize UI++]

- Download the extension
- Go into user settings.json and put this:

`"apc.stylesheet": { ".pane-body": "zoom: 1.123; transform-origin: 0 0;", }`