# Is there a way in vscode to only zoom in on the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, when you zoom in while using vscode, the editor, side panel, and icons all get magnified.

Does anyone know how to get functionality similar to Atom where only the editor gets larger?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want the [FontSize Shortcuts extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fosshaas.fontsize-shortcuts).

[image]

Installation:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. `ext install fontsize-shortcuts`
3. Restart Visual Studio Code.

The shortcuts are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to increase the font size.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the font size.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset the font size.

Comment: this extension doesn't work very well anymore, at least not on mac (e.g. increasing the font does not work)

Comment: The docs cannot seem to agree if you use the `=` or `+` key to zoom in. As far as I can tell you must use `=`, which means you can't use the numeric keypad. When you do `Ctrl` + `+` you get the entire IDE zooming in and out, but with `=` it's just the font size.

Comment: Your link now goes to a 404 page.

Comment: @ScottTesler Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Why this feature does not build-in on VS installation (Very very basic idea). hh very weird (Imagine on chrome you need to download extension for zoom in-out page). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 148):

Out of Box solution for zoom in/out for text only:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P (or View->Command Palette...)
2. Type Open User Settings
3. Edit settings.json
4. Add "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
5. Save it.

You can use your mouse wheel to zoom in or zoom out only text in the text box.

Comment: How to reset this?

Comment: Found it. See [cezn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783324/3645375) answer

Comment: In case you aren't using a mouse you hold `Ctrl` + drag two fingers on your touchpad instead

Comment: This is the best answer. No need for plugins.

Comment: In newer versions of Visual Studio Code (tested on v.1.33.1) , you don't need to manually edit the settings.json file. The Settings tab has the option - you just need to search for Mouse Wheel Zoom in the search bar, and check the 'Zoom the font of the editor when using the mouse wheel and holding Ctrl' option.

Comment: this even turns on the "pinch to zoom" in mac. GREAT WORK

Comment: why on earth isn't this on by default.. thanks for this!

Answer (score 63):

#### Update [Version 1.24](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_font-zoom-commands) - May 2018

There are new commands for to zoom in/zoom out text in editors only:

- `Editor Font Zoom In`
- `Editor Font Zoom Out`
- `Editor Font Zoom Reset`

By default they don't have any keybindings assigned:

[image: screenshot of font zoom commands]

Comment: Does your version still have these settings? I cannot seem to find them in the current 1.60

Answer (score 5):

1. `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the Command Palette
2. Type `Editor Font Zoom In`
3. Press `Enter`
4. Repeat until the font is the desired size

Comment: Hi Edward. This answer seems to be duplicating the steps already provided in the existing answers. Please try to avoid answering questions that already have suitable answers unless there is a unique solution to present to the community. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 4):

**To change the keyboard shortcuts so they only zoom the editor font, you just need to:**

1. Open the Command Palette `(Control+Shift+P)` and type Keyboard Shortcuts. Choose `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Search for `zoom.` You'll see a few results, including those for global zoom and editor font zoom.
   3)If you want to replace the global zoom shortcuts with editor font zoom, you first need to remove the keybindings from `View: Zoom In` and `View: Zoom Out`. You can right-click them and choose `Remove Keybinding` or select them and hit the delete key.
3. Add the new keybindings for `Editor Font Zoom In` and `Editor Font Zoom Out`. You just select `Editor Font Zoom In` and click the `+` on the left hand side, type the keybinding you want (eg. `Control+Shift+=`) and then press enter.

Note: you might need to open new VS Code windows for these changes to take effect. If the keyboard shortcuts are still zooming the whole interface, you'll need to make sure that you have removed the keybindings from `View: Zoom In` and `View: Zoom Out` (see step 3 above)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I cannot comment, but this is an update on cezn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783324/8538706) and wruckie's question beneath it.

I also do not have these options in 1.64.2, however there is an `Editor: Mouse Wheel Zoom` option. Find it by searching for `zoom`. Works like a charm by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

[image: mouse wheel zoom setting]

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings
2. Then, Swap to Workspace tab at the top
3. at last, Change Editor: Font Size

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change it as default.
Try these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio Code.
2. Type command CTRL + SHFT + P.
3. Type Settings.
   The settings file will open.
4. Now under User > Text Editor > Font, find Font Size.
5. Enter your desired font size.

Answer (score 0):

1. Command+Shift+P (or View->Command Palette...)
2. Search "editor font zoom"

You can zoom in, zoom out or reset to default and only the editor window will be effected.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the keyboard shortcuts page, then search up "Editor Font Zoom", there should be some shortcuts you can bind to keys.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I believe this is already covered by the existing answers

Answer (score 0):

1.- Go to Settings:

File -> Preferences -> Settings (`Ctrl` + `,`)

2.- Go to the font size settings:

Text Editor -> Font -> Font Size

3.- Set the desired font size, this will only apply to the editor but not to the rest of the application.

[image]