# How to change font size in VS Code sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, font-size, sidebar

Querying for `fontsize` in `User Settings` window yields only settings for:

- editor panes,
- suggest widget,
- markdown preview,
- integrated terminal

As you can see below:

[image]

Doing the same for `sidebar` gives even poorer results:

[image]

Having fonts of different sizes in editor panes and sidebar looks... let's settle with: *not too nice*. Have I just found the greatest omission of this awesome tool?

Comment: See also: [How to reset VS Code's window zoom setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69748790/4561887)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has been a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519) for some time. The short answer is right now there's no VSCode setting that allows you to customize the sidebar font size. There is a hacky workaround solution proposed by [@lindesvard in the same issue thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519#issuecomment-387007363) that involves using the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension to load in a custom CSS file that modifies the sidebar styling if you're willing to experiment with it.

To get this working follow the Getting Started section in the extension details, then add URLs to your custom files to the `"vscode_custom_css.imports": [""]` array. (Note that on Windows mine looks like the following: `"vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///C:\\dev\\vscode-styling.css"]`)

Below are before and after adding the CSS mentioned by [@PSVapour in a later comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519#issuecomment-387148025):

[image: Original] [image: Modified]

Note that this also affects the command palette font.

Comment: Good answer. I'll only add that there's also a simpler workaround of zooming out with `CTRL`+`-` to make all fonts smaller and then adjusting the ones we have control over accordingly. This however has a downside of scaling down also other UI elements like editor panes' tabs. It suited me, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Yes, that's a far simpler alternative indeed. Perhaps you could post it as an answer to give it more visibility.

Comment: i followed every bits mentioned in, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css and copy and paste the following to custom css file but it did not work ..monaco-tree-row.has-children {
font-weight: 500;
margin: 8px;
color: #eee;
font-size: 14px;
}

.monaco-tree-row {
font-weight: 300;
margin: 5px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #bbb;
}

Answer (score 230):

Just want to add to the discussion, If you set:

```
"window.zoomLevel": "your number",
```

In my case I started with zero, you can use that as sort of a baseline:

```
"editor.fontSize": 14,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
"window.zoomLevel": -1.5,
"[Log]": {
  "editor.fontSize": 14
},
```

And then tweaked until I was happy.

E.g. you want to increase the sidebar font size keeping editor font size unchanged: set `"window.zoomLevel": -1.2` and `"editor.fontSize": 18`. Look at the result. Play with both values to get the result you like.

Comment: The only thing missing from this answer is where to find the settings file. I was able to set the zoom level via the following: `Sidebar > Manage > Settings > Window > Zoom Level`. Then `Text Editor > Font > Font Size`

Comment: @B2K Hi there! If you go to `Code > Preferences > Settings` you'll go to the GUI/pane for Settings, but then go to the top right, you'll see three icons, click the first one (from the left ) and it will take you to the `settings.json` file.

Comment: Alternative you can just hit `⌘=` to zoom, then adjust font.

Comment: while this works, it is not the correct answer, because the question asks to increase font size only, while this answer increases the bars, menu sizes and actually everything that is not text related.

Comment: @makkasi I think the point is that you can't edit the sidebar directly, but you can edit the "base" UI size and then edit the other text sizes to your preferences, which nearly reduces to the same thing. The downside, as you remark, is that there are side effects, but it does change the operative sidebar font size.

Comment: `"editor.fontSize"` is very helpful! Upvoted. I wrote more about just the zoom level here: [Everything there is to know about VSCode window zoom: zoom in and out, reset zoom, use fractional values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519384/4561887), including resetting to default, using fractional values, etc.

Answer (score 64):

[Mihai Chelaru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457258/4465708) presents a way to do more than just adjust the sidebar's font size. This, however, comes with a price of *a bit of fiddling*, possibly more than you'd be ready for, if the only thing you were interested in was the simple act of changing the sidebar's font size. So here's a simpler solution.

Just zoom the whole VS Code's UI in or out with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> respectively and than adjust font sizes we do have control over in `settings.json` file, i.e.:

- `editor.fontSize`,
- `editor.suggestFontSize`,
- `markdown.preview.fontSize`,
- `terminal.integrated.fontSize`

so everything matches. That's it.

Comment: I do this way also. However, sidebar's font either becomes 10 or 12, not 11 which I like. So I set the editor and terminal font size to 13, zoom out 1. The editor becomes 11, sidebar becomes 10. I can live with that at the moment.

Answer (score 17):

Apart from [@Mihai Chelaru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457258/4465708), I found another plugin which helped me dealing with this issue. The name of the plugin is [**`CustomizeUI`**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui).

**`CustomizeUI`** relies on the [**`Monkey Patch Extension`**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch) to inject custom javascript in VSCode. Here is the settings I use (in `settings.json`) for my Mac:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".explorer-viewlet .mac": "font-size: 1.2em !important; overflow: auto; border-left:none!important",
},
```

Again, this plugin is meant to do more than just changing the font size of the sidebar. But it has some minor advantages over Custom CSS and JS Loader. Like:

- It won't show `Unsupported` on the title-bar or won't show any error message like `Your installation is corrupted`.
- You do not have to reload settings every time VS Code is updated.

---

**As of 29-02-2024 this extension(s) is no longer being maintained**
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the best answer. It is the easiest. Also it doesn't increase the size of the icon bar, neither of the top bar. This way I don't lose space. Thank you.

Comment: Be aware it looks like there is a bug currently with this extension: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184805

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! I just installed this plugin which required a restart. When I restarted, all of my settings were gone, and the extensions tab in the sidebar won't even open so I can't disable the extension!

Comment: You can disable Monkey Patch by pressing ctrl+p and type "Disable Monkey Patch" as mentioned in the extension.

Answer (score 6):

You can **zoom in** and **zoom out**:

**zoom in**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

**zoom out**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: sometimes the editor font is larger than the sidebar menu, actually, it is by default and your solution increases everything making the editor font extremely large.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font size with keyboard shortcuts using the FontSize Shortcuts
plugin. On a Mac, I am able to focus on the terminal or the editor and change the font size of those areas independently of each other.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fosshaas.fontsize-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

[Mihai's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456526/how-to-change-font-size-in-vs-code-sidebar/51457258#51457258) works well. He notes that [the CSS from here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519#issuecomment-387148025) has the side effect of changing the command palette font too.

I only wanted to specify the font size for the debugger sidebar tab. At the time of writing (VS Code version 1.74.3), this custom CSS instead affects only the debugger sidebar tab:

```css
.debug-pane,
.debug-pane .scope,
.debug-pane .expression {
  font-size: 14px !important
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"window.titleBarStyle":"native", and Toggle Memu Bar off

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).