# How to make vs code folder icon bigger & text to white?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make vs code folder icon bigger & text to white? I use material design theme for vs code.

[image: VS code screebshot]

Comment: You can try using this link https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=high+contrast

Answer (score 9):

To change the sidebar font color use:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBar.foreground": "#fff"
}
```

To change the icon size, you probably have to change the zoom level of the whole app, and then decrease your editor.fontsize to your liking.  See [changing the sidebar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040857/visual-studio-code-change-font-size-for-file-explorer-tray).  I don't think you can increase the icon sizes and not the accompanying sidebar font sizes at the same time.

The issue is being tracked, see [customize the sidebar please](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519).

Answer (score 3):

I have done some research on how to make icons size bigger in VSCode sidebar and found the only way i.e. load custom CSS.

This can be achieved with custom CSS and JS loader extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css
For installation and setup please refer instruction from this link page.

Create a css file on your system with any name you like and paste this css in that file.

```css
.sidebar .monaco-list-row {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar .codicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .monaco-icon-label:before {
  background-size: 20px;
}
```

Note: Font size related changes are optional and you can change background-size as per your need.

Save this file after paste and copy this file's path.
Open VSCode Settings and click on JSON option

[image]

After that paste this line in settings.

```
"vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///cssFilePath"],
```

After doing this, the setting will look like this.

[image]

In my case I am using linux. The file path structure may vary in case of windows or mac.

Once that is done, press ctrl+sfift+p to open VSCode command palette.
Type Enable Custom CSS and JS and press enter.
It will trigger one popup at bottom like this.

[image]

Click on Restart Visual Studio Code button from that popup.

The icon size will be updated after restart.
In case it won't, you can open command palette again and type Reload custom CSS and JS and press Enter.
It will again give you popup and ask for restart, and once you restart the icon size be updated.

Final result will look like this

[image]