# How to increase the size of icons and text in the navigation bar Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, panel, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to increase the size of icons and text in the navigation bar but found in the settings and the command Ctrl += Enlarges everything entirely

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make vs code folder icon bigger & text to white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832452/how-to-make-vs-code-folder-icon-bigger-text-to-white)