# How to resize sections in the vscode sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The vscode sidebar has several sections like "outline", "open files" and the folder view.

I cannot see how I can resize the outline section (that is only about 5 lines high in my view). I can open and close it, but I do not see how to resize it. It can be dragged up and down to change its position, but there seems to be no option to change the vertical size.

Update:
Now I can drag the lower boundary of the section and it works without any problems. Yesterday I could not find a handle below the section.
I have no idea what is changed, so I now just accept the trivial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the border of the section and resize it as you like:

[image]

Comment: Today it just worked for me, when I yesterday really could not find a handle below the section. I have no idea what's different. Can this be related to sections added by addons?

Comment: I think, no. I have some extra sections added by Mongo and Jest, no behavior changes so far. But it may be somehow related to VSCode version. You can try to use the latest available version (or even proceed with VSCode Insiders) and enable your plugins one-by-one. However, I didn't have any problems with that as well.

Comment: It work for me now and it looks like it should have worked like this all the time. When I notice some pattern when it does not work I reopen the question, otherwise it probably was just me not finding the separator :-/.

Comment: It only works for me when the view is not full and I can click the background. This highlights the edges of the interior of the view in blue, and then the bottom edge becomes draggable. If it's full already, I can't find a way.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson Seems like there is something wrong with your VS Code instance. Just tried my VS Code Insiders (version 1.71.0-insider) in both fullscreen and windowed modes, the edges become draggable, and the resize icon does appear. You can try to clear the app cache and update to the latest available version.

Comment: Clearing the cache folders had no effect. I'm running 1.71.0 (non-insider).

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut: Hold **Command** and tap **-/+** key to resize

Answer (score 0):

**Vertical** size is depends on screen size, **horizontal** size you can change by moving this:

[image]

Comment: My problem is the vertical size, horizontal resizing works fine. There is a lot of unused space in the file list, but the outline requires scrolling.

Comment: There is just two options - increase font size or change zoom.
[sidebar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774918/vs-code-customize-sidebar)